# CouchDB listen to _changes feed

Tags: php, javascript, couchdb

I have a small website which I want to listen to the _changes feed on a couch database I have.
The website displays a list of elements from the database, and when a change happens to the database I want the list to refresh it self. Keep in mind that the client making the change isn't necessarily the one who views the list.

I've tried a bit of googling, but haven|t found what I'm looking for.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

The upcoming CouchDB 1.3 will support an [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/EventSource) version of the _changes feed, which you can consume directly from JavaScript. With older CouchDB versions, I don't think you can do anything like that, so you'd need some sort of proxy (converting the continuous _changes feed to EventSource or WebSocket format) in between.